# Implement Java annotations for validation

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

I want to call a Validator from `org.hibernate.validator.internal.constraintvalidators.` manually on a value because I can't annotate the class. What I've done is this :

```
LengthValidator validator = new LengthValidator();
validator.initialize(new Length() {
    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int min() {
        return min == null ? defaultMin : min;
    }

    @Override
    public String message() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int max() {
        return max == null ? defaultMax : max;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?>[] groups() {
        return null;
    }
});
Boolean valid = validator.isValid(myValue.asText(), null));
```

But Sonar is not happy :

> Lambdas and anonymous classes should not have too many lines

So I tried to refactor this code by implementing @Length in a custom class like this :

```
public class StringLength implements Length {
    // All the methods overriden from @Length
}
```

but the compiler complains

> The annotation type Length should not be used as a superinterface for
>   StringLength

How can I achieve what I want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the use of internal classes is not encouraged, but if you really wanted to, you could use the Hibernate Validator `AnnotationFactory`:

```
  AnnotationDescriptor<Length> descriptor = new AnnotationDescriptor<Length>( Length.class );
  descriptor.setValue( "min", 0 );
  descriptor.setValue( "max", 10 );
  ...

  Length lengthAnnotation = AnnotationFactory.create( descriptor );
```

I am not quite sure though, what you gain using `LengthValidator`. You still cannot make use of the Validator framework, right? If you cannot annotate the class, can you not use XML configuration instead?

Comment: In fact, I want to validate schemaless data and I don't want to rewrite validators that work perfectly in Hibernate. So I can't use XML configuration since I don't know the structure of the data to validate. That's why I want to build annotations and call validators "dynamically". I'm going to try `AnnotationDescriptor` ;)